# Opening ModalPopupExtender Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Popup in my aspx page that i want to open based on criteria that has to be met by javascript. The problem i am having is that i cannot seem to get the modalpopupextender to work no matter what i try.

I have tried using PageMethods, _doPostBack() and $Find(PopupClientId).Show();

None of the above seem to work and i cannot figure out why.

This is my JavaScript.

```
    function RequotePopup(popup, status) {
        if (status = true) {
            var thePopup = document.getElementById(popup);
            thePopup.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            alert("Please select a record for Re-Quote");
        }
    }
    function checkGridView() {
        var hdnCheckboxIDs = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnCheckboxID");
        var arrCheckboxIDs = hdnCheckboxIDs.value.split(",");
        var checked = false;


        for (var i = 0; i < arrCheckboxIDs.length; i++) {
            if (arrCheckboxIDs[i] != "") {
                var ckbItem = document.getElementById(arrCheckboxIDs[i]);
                if (ckbItem != null) {
                    if (ckbItem.checked == true) {
                        checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (checked == true) {
            //var modal = $find('<%= ReQuoteBtn_ModalPopupExtender.ClientID %>');
            //modal.show();
            PageMethods.ShowExtender();
            ShowPopup('RequotePopup');
        } else {
            alert("Please select a record for Re-Quote");
        }
    }
```

And This is my ASP.Net.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />

<asp:Button ID="ReQuoteBtn" runat="server" Text="Re-Quote" OnClientClick="Javascript:checkGridView()"
    CssClass="Sales" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ReQuoteBtn_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" Enabled="True" BehaviorID="RequoteModal" PopupControlID="RequotePopup"
    TargetControlID="ReQuoteBtn" OnCancelScript="cmdCancelrq">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: Have you checked the reference to the AjaxControlToolkit and maybe remove/re-add it yet, just to be sure?

Comment: I know that the AjaxControlToolkit works because it is being used on the majority of pages in the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have tried this, but it should work if you find the ModalPopupExtender by **BehaviorID**.

As your BehaviorID is **RequoteModal**, let try this sample:

To show the popup

```
$find('RequoteModal').show();
```

To hide the popup

```
$find('RequoteModal').hide();
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed that you set `Enabled="False"` for the **ModalPopupExtender**, this will not allow the modal to call show() method, you may got error message such **"Unable to get property 'show' of undefined or null reference".**

Please remove that setting and try again.

Comment: I have tried this but i still get a null reference in `modal`.

Comment: Why do you need to set **Enabled="False"** for ModalPopupExtender?

Comment: I was testing another theory. I shall update it with my current code.

Comment: How about a vanilla javascript example?